# How to properly run NodeJs on Windows Server in production

Tags: node.js, windows, pm2

I am having difficult times, trying to make my NodeJS scripts run on windows server 2012. Or more precisely, to make it robust.

I have installed PM2, whic his great, also added service for windows startup which works fine, but now I  found biggest issue I can't solve.
When windows server user start pm2 start, directly on server or through ssh, when logging out, all pm2 scripts are gone.
I've tried to look into pm2-windows-service but that seems inconsistent, when I restart service, it works fine, but sometimes I need to manually reload o restart only 1 script and then whole list of pm2 scripts gets somehow detached or attached to user, so when I log out from server it's all gone again.

I can't find solution to have watcher/autorestart on scripts, and make them run as a service regardless of user being logged in/out.

There must be solution for running multiple nodejs scripts on windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you launch your NodeJS processes, you should run `pm2 save` command. That way, your stated scripts are saved.

Your attached/dettached problems may be due a relative path configuration in the service env variables. Try moving to an absolute path.

**Note**: PM2 recommendation is to launch commands with an admin-privileged user; otherwise inconsistences may appear.

**Note (2)**: Bare in mind that PM2 on Windows has some issues. For example, if you restart your server, most of the times processes dissapear from `pm2 ls` (they noted that Windows does not have the feature to restore saved instances). If you saved them, `pm2 resurrect` will restore them.

Comment: I am doing everything you said. My biggest problem is, I can't keep my processes running when user is signing out.  It's all nice when user stays logged in, but like recently it happens that someone logged in with remote desktop, and then signed out the user which killed all pm2 started scripts. I can't find a way to prevent that

Comment: mmmmm, Are your users doing Windows -> Logout?? That could make sense to your problem. I usually just close remote desktop window (without closing session). But that's why you have a service. Have you check all config on `pm2-windows-service`?

Comment: yes that's exactly what's happening, Most of the time we are just closing remote desktop and it's fine. But last time someone actually logged out admin user. But I also noticed, if I connect with ssh to it, and do pm2 start, and close ssh it also kills all services. I am looking into pm2-windows-service , I will have to test it more in details, but it looks like that's what I need in theory. I am just surprised that NodeJS doesn't have something to monitor processes, it makes me i want to rewrite my APIs in php.

Comment: Yeah, I faced similar problems. We ended up with only 1 user on the server. I've look on Internet, because it is an interesting problem that we may face. Check these GitHub issues: https://github.com/jon-hall/pm2-windows-service/issues/25 and https://github.com/jon-hall/pm2-windows-service/issues/5